# Programmatic creation of rules

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule

Suppose I am given two positions, as well as `b[0, 0]` and `b[0, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1]/Sqrt[2]`, where `b` is some undefined symbol, so that the expressions remain in an unevaluated form. I would like to create the following rule: whenever the argument of `b` in position 1 is `0` and the argument in position 2 is `0`, replace this using the latter expression. For example, let's say the positions are just the first and second arguments, and I have several expressions of the form `b[x,y,z]`. Looking at what I am given, I can manually write down the rule like below.

```
rule=b[0, 0, x_] -> b[0, 1, x]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, x]/Sqrt[2]
```

Then I would have

```
b[0,0,0]/. rule
(*b[0, 1, 0]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, 0]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

and

```
b[0,0,1]/.rule
(*b[0, 1, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, 1]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

Here's my attempt at  creating the rule programmatically (I haven't gotten around to making this work for given positions yet, so assuming first and second argument).

```
rule=b[0, 0] -> b[0, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1]/Sqrt[2] /. 
b[x_, y_] -> b[x, y, Blank[]]
```

But this doesn't give me what I want, because the `Blank[]` is not named and I don't know how to make it named since it is in the r.h.s. of the rule.

```
b[0,0,0]/. rule
(*b[0, 1, _]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, _]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you need is to replace all of the occurrences of `b[x, y]` in a rule with `b[x, y, z_]` where `x` and `y` are constants and `z` is a pattern object to be matched.  To start with, you need to use `RuleDelayed` (written as `:>`), then you use `z_` on the right hand side, like this:

```
(b[0, 0] -> b[0, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1]/Sqrt[2]) /. b[x_, y_] :> b[x, y, z_]
(*b[0, 0, z_] -> b[0, 1, z_]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, z_]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

Though the output is still not quite right, as the output rule has `z_` on the right hand side.  So to fix this you need to match the pattern of the `Rule`, then modify the left and right separately, like this:

```
rule = (
  b[0, 0] -> b[0, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1]/Sqrt[2]
) /. {
  Rule[left_, right_] :> RuleDelayed[
    Append[left, z_], 
    Evaluate[right /. {b[x_, y_] :> b[x, y, z]}]
  ]
} /. z$->z
(*b[0, 0, z_] :> b[0, 1, z]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, z]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

To go through the elements:

- The parenthesis at the start contain the rule you are modifying
- `Rule[left_, right_]` matches to your rule
- `RuleDelayed` makes a new rule (for the output)
- `Append[left, z_]` adds the new pattern object z to the left hand side of the rule (using a `ReplaceAll` here does not substitute in the constants properly)
- The `Evaluate` on the right hand side of the output replacement is because we are trying to output a `RuleDelayed`, meaning the right hand side will be left unevaluated by default.
- `/. z$->z` at the end fixes an automatic substitution of `z$` into your rule (to do with automatic scoping)

And to test:

```
b[0, 0, 1] /. rule
(*b[0, 1, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1, 1]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

Note that you will need to make sure you clear `z` before you use this rule otherwise its value will be substituted in.

It's not the neatest solution but it should reliably do what you need.

Comment: +1, to avoid relying on `z$` renaming you could go with something like `Module[{h}, 
 h[Append[left, z_], right /. {b[x_, y_] :> b[x, y, z]}] /. 
  h -> RuleDelayed]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my swing at trying to solve this. First define this function:

```
ruleTransform[yourRule_] := 
  MapAt[
    Append[#, x_] &,
    yourRule,
    1
  ] /. b[a1_, a2_] :> b[a1, a2, x]
```

Next, you throw in the rule you want to change:

```
ruleTransform[b[0, 0] -> b[0, 1]/Sqrt[2] + b[1, 1]/Sqrt[2]]
```

This should give you the rule you needed.